# If a library linked twice, how does program determine which version to use?

Tags: linker, dependencies, shared-libraries

I have been trapped in following situation when writing a shared library for a server.

To make it easy to understand:

1. let's call the server framework fwA
2. the shared library written by me called libB
3. different versions of the library linked both by fwA and libB named as libC1 and libC2

And fwA loads libB by dllopen

Following is my question:
There is a data structure (DS1) is defined in libC, however, in libC1 and libC2 the data structure is slightly different.

How do compiler/linker/program determine which version of the data structure they would use?

Answer (score 0):

If the structure definition is different in `libC1` and `libC2`, then surely somewhere it will access wrong offset. Its undefined behaviour. We should not use like this.

Answer (score 0):

Data structures are not objects, so the linker does not see them directly. Each library will assume their layout.

This can work if the actual instances of the data structures are not shared between different versions. For example, in your scenario, you are fine as long as no such structures are passed between fwA and libB. The communication between fwA and libC1 is safe, as is libB and libC2.

The Windows world does this all the time: every DLL that calls into `malloc` and `free` will be linked against a specific version of the C runtime, and possibly even use inline functions to access allocator data structures.

That is fully acceptable as long as the DLL that allocated an object is also responsible for freeing it. Thus, if your library has

```
foo *alloc_foo() { return (foo *)malloc(sizeof(foo)); }
```

then it is not safe to call `free(my_foo);` on the pointer received because the DLL might be using a different allocator implementation. Instead, use their provided

```
void free_foo(foo *fp) { free(fp); }
```

Thus, the interface between fwA and libB should be designed so that it has no dependencies on the libC ABI, otherwise the libC ABI becomes part of the libB ABI as well.